# Simple json reading the api

Tags: javascript, json

I have a query that produces the following results:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1107702400"
    },
    {
      "id": "1149862205",
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Penelope Test",
            "category": "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
            "id": "411133928921438",
            "created_time": "2012-05-23T11:41:27+0000"
          },
```

The first id I can access through:

```
response.data[i].id
```

How do I retrieve the second id?  (the one that goes data-id-data-id ?)

I have this function:

```
for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++)
            {
                 testdiv.innerHTML +=  response.data.data[i].id + '<br/>' ;
            }
```

Which lets me print the first id.

What do I need to do in order to print the second id?

Comment: `response.data[1].likes.data[0].id`

Comment: Hey thanks :)
Correct, i have this one question please,
I have a query which let's me print the first id, but i need to print the second id for each first id something like this... please see my updated code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example data

```
response.data[i].likes.data[0].id
```

Comment: Yeah, was posted while I was typing, had to laugh when I read it.